# Percentage/progress Counter on SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list

I have a list in SharePoint that sends an automatic email out to a group of people upon submission. I wanted to explore the possibility of doing a percentage/progress bar indicator that will let people know in the subject line how complete the list item is. For example: There are drop down options that have options of "In folder", "Attached", "n/a", and "Not yet available". If something is "Not yet available" then it would be considered incomplete and the percentage would reflect that. There is a way I could do it with conditional statements and a dozen different email templates, but if the list columns were ever to change, I would need to change it for 10+ email templates and I figured there must be an easier way that I'm missing.

Comment: Could be done with a calculated column which checks for `if not (<field> == <Not yet available>) then (<progress of field> = 1) else (<progress of field> = 0)`. Then you'd still need a `<progress>` field to iterate the `<progress of field>`s. This is a clumsy pseudo example utilizing assisting fields. The whole implementation could probably be built with one single calculated column. The update process of such isn't too terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way you can have the following conditions which require a change in one place if there is a change to your field.

- Set workflow variable (status) to Current List Item Dropdown field
- Create a workflow variable (temp status) for your email subject
- Create a workflow variable (percentage)
- The conditions can be as follows

```
IF status is "In Folder"
   set workflow variable temp status to "In Progress"
   set workflow variable percentage to "10"
IF status is "Not yet available"
   set workflow variable temp status to "Not Complete"
   set workflow variable percentage to "50"
```

- Add a email action
- Set Subject line. (Add your workflow varibales to subject line)

This approach requires a change at one place where you are setting workflow variable

Let me know if I am missing anything here